# Phonegap Filesystem keeps saving to internal storage while there is an SD card

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm having trouble using the phonegap file API. In my application I'm using the following piece of code to save images from the LocalStorage to the android device.

`window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSys) {
            // If the folder does not exist create it
                fileSys.root.getDirectory( myFolderApp, {
                    create:true, exclusive: false
                },
                function(directory) {
                    entry.moveTo(directory, newFileName,  successMove, resOnError);
                },
            resOnError);
            }`

the variable myFolderApp contains the foldername that needs to be created. The problem is that even tough the android tablet has got an SD card inserted, the applicaton keeps creating the directory (and later saving the data) to the internal storage instead of the external SD card.

localFileSystem.PERSISTENT Should switch to sd card when one is available right?
When I log   the directory.toURL() it's saying "cdvfile/localhost/persistent/mydirectory"

The native android camera application is saving it's images to the SD card which means the SD card is working properly.

I'm quite lost at this point. After hours of googeling I know the cordova file plugin has recently been updated, and therefore sometimes requires a different approach but I'm still stuck and can't seem to find a solution.

Hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance,

Marco

Answer (score 0):

Try changing in config.xml

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
```

to

```
<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
```

See the following discussion:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phonegap/5UeZOBAz_DM/YlaGFJVCpv4J

Answer (score 0):

We need to modify the AndroidManifest.xml file,  however we will not do it manually. This is not a good practice as everytime you build your project, your changes will be lost.

Instead we are going to use the cordova-custom-config plugin, which allow you to modify the AndroidManifest.xml file from your config.xml file without problems. To install the plugin execute the following command in your command line :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-custom-config
# Or phonegap
phonegap plugin add cordova-custom-config
```

Fortunately, to enable this feature you need add only a property to the AndroidManifest.xml file. Using cordova-custom-config plugin, which allow you to use custom config blocks in your config.xml file of your cordova app, you need to add the following line in the config.xml file inside the  tag :

```
<platform name="android">
   <!-- Modify the android-manifest block and add the new property android:installLocation with value auto !-->
   <preference name="android-manifest/@android:installLocation" value="auto" />
</platform>
```

Read more about step by step [here.](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/171/how-to-enable-the-move-to-sd-card-feature-in-a-cordova-app-for-android)

Read more about the plugin here in the official repository [here.](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config)